# output file parser issue, unexpected output

Tags: python

import re
from itertools import islice
dnlist = []
maclist = []

with open('bulkdn.txt','r') as lines:
     for line in lines:
         if '@ttml' in line:
             dn = re.findall(r'\d{10}',line)
             dnlist.append(dn)
         if 'svc:1' in line:
             mac = re.findall(r'mac:[a-fA-F0-9]{2}[:][a-fA-AF0-9]{2}[:][a-fA-F0-9]{2}[:][a-fA-F0-9]{2}[:][a-fA-F0-9]{2}[:][a-fA-F0-9]{2}',line)
             maclist.append(mac)

```
 i=0        #next
 for dn,mac in zip(dnlist,maclist):
     print('{} {}{}'.format(i,dn,mac))
     i+=1
```

Input file as below

User-Name
  Descr.

### Up Time       Type  Termination     IP/L2TP-Id/Interface-Id MC-Stdby

-
  svc:1 sap:lag-50:1776.2000 mac:00:17:7c:75:99:75 sid:5421

### 0d 00:02:38   oE    local           N/A

svc:1 sap:lag-50:2680.2000 mac:00:17:7c:6d:d6:2b sid:4099

### 0d 00:01:30   oE    local           N/A

svc:1 sap:lag-50:2805.2000 mac:00:17:7c:80:e2:fb sid:1796

### 0d 00:01:00   oE    local           N/A

svc:1 sap:lag-50:2813.2000 mac:e4:6f:13:c0:13:9a sid:2420

### 0d 00:00:22   oE    local           N/A

svc:1 sap:lag-50:1715.3615 mac:10:62:eb:66:24:be sid:6612

### 0d 00:00:05   oE    local           N/A

svc:1 sap:lag-50:62.3602 mac:00:17:7c:83:51:24 sid:902

### 0d 00:00:03   oE    local           N/A

svc:1 sap:lag-50:65.3605 mac:00:17:7c:7c:fa:f9 sid:1200

### 0d 00:00:02   oE    local           N/A

svc:1 sap:lag-50:1714.3614 mac:78:32:1b:99:a0:f9 sid:1178

### 0d 00:00:02   oE    local           N/A

svc:1 sap:lag-50:2585.2000 mac:00:17:7c:7c:24:42 sid:7710
           0d 00:00:01   oE    local           N/A
0200200003@ttml
  svc:1 sap:lag-50:1775.2000 mac:00:17:7c:78:74:56 sid:7151
           0d 01:08:06   oE    local           114.143.122.39
0200200006@ttml
  svc:1 sap:lag-50:2851.3739 mac:00:17:7c:77:ab:26 sid:2664
           0d 07:26:23   oE    local           49.248.206.250
                                               01:4A:83:6A:03:4A:83:6A
0200200008@ttml
  svc:1 sap:lag-50:79.3609 mac:80:26:89:ca:62:8b sid:4849
           0d 00:28:31   oE    local           49.248.169.78
                                               82:26:89:FF:FE:CA:62:8B
0200200015@ttml
  svc:1 sap:lag-50:73.3603 mac:6c:72:20:49:8b:6e sid:7559
           0d 02:28:27   oE    local           49.248.177.166
                                               6E:72:20:FF:FE:49:8B:6E
0200200016@ttml
  svc:1 sap:lag-50:1720.3620 mac:00:17:7c:7d:41:22 sid:7539
           0d 02:52:09   oE    local           49.248.48.145

expected output is
0200200015 mac:6c:72:20:49:8b:6e
0200200008 mac:80:26:89:ca:62:8b
0200200016 mac:00:17:7c:7d:41:22

Comment: Please make you code and question more readable !

Answer (score 0):

I'm ignoring the fact that your code does not format the same as you expect as I think that it is the mac address not matching up with the dn that is the problem you are asking about.

Basically you are matching mac addresses and dns, but there are 14 macs and 5 dns according to the regex you have defined.

I would match both the dn and the mac at the same time with a multiline regex like this. I haven't optimised this regex, but left it as verbose as possible so it's self-explanatory. Basically though it matches the dn, various static bits of text then a mac shaped string. We find them all, and that's the answer!

```
import re

with open('bulkdn.txt','r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    r = re.compile(r"^([0-9]{10})\@ttml$\s*svc:1\s.*\smac:([0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2})", re.MULTILINE)
    ms = r.findall(text)

    for m in ms:
        print(m)
```

Result:

```
('0200200003', '00:17:7c:78:74:56')
('0200200006', '00:17:7c:77:ab:26')
('0200200008', '80:26:89:ca:62:8b')
('0200200015', '6c:72:20:49:8b:6e')
('0200200016', '00:17:7c:7d:41:22')
```